# Redirect issue in codeigniter with using tank auth social

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, tankauth

i want to login my website with facebook and save the user data into the database, for this i am using tank auth social libray, every thing is perfectly fine but when i click to login with facebook it shows me an error like that

```
   An error occurred. Please try again later.

     API Error Code: 191
     API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
     Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

what's the problem in it, i can't understand where i wrong i m using step by step but i don't know what's this problem, is there any one help i will ber very thankfull to him, than ks a ton in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Facebook application "owns" by default the canvas url `http://apps.facebook.com/your_app`, but also a given domain which you have to enter. The `redirect_uri` is for security reasons only able to redirect you to either.

If you're unable to make this work, you can have the `redirect_uri` to point to a site such as `http://apps.facebook.com/my_redirect` and simply have **controllers/my_redirect.php**'s `index` function to `echo <script>top.location = 'http://google.com'</script>` for example.

Regardless, check your settings in your application, and read up on these errors more since a lot people have posted them and gotten answers for them aswell.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set your application URL in facebook application settings

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```